# C# Creating a class with a list constructor of its own class

Tags: c#, class, constructor

So I have the following class with constructors:

```
public class dataEntry : XMLSerializable<dataEntry>
{
    public string name;
    public string value;
    public List<dataEntry> data;
```

The idea is that a dataEntry must have a name and either a single value or a list of more data entries.  Then, each of those data entries in the list must have a name and either a single value or another list etc. eventually ending in nested dataEntries that contain just a name and value.

When I try making the constructors, I am getting an error:
The type or namespace name 'List' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Is this not possible? I find it odd because I am able to create a non-list constructor of the same class without any issue.

Thank you for any help/insights.

Comment: add a `using System.Collection.Generic` at the top of your file.

Comment: See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324575/c-sharp-class-with-recursion)